# Using other indicatives of Allah in writing

Tags: adab, asma-ul-husna

I don't want to write Allah (Subhannahu wata'ala) in my notebook because I may (accidentally) drop my notebook on the floor plenty of times, and I will probably throw the notebook away at the end of the school year, so that would be disrespectful to the name of our Creator.

If I write "Who's in the sky" or "Who created the skies and the Earth" or other indications of Allah (may He be Exalted and Glorified), **will I also be required to respect the notebook?**

Jazakum Allah khayran,

Comment: I suppose that what applies for qur'an text on mobile phones etc. applies for names of Allah on the same devices: the matter isn't that complicated and at least it is up to you and your interpretation of adab in this context.